# Error with :Own javascript slider for wordpress - Hover function?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I created an slider that slide all images of my wordpress articles,
and if you go over an image, it shows you the title an link.
My Problem is if the mouse goes over the title or link in the box, it disapears and turn flashing until i leave the whole div.

Code myownslider.js:

```
$('.SliderImages ul li').mouseover(function(){
    slideActive=false;
    $('.SliderTooltips li#st_'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","block");
});
$('.SliderImages ul li').mouseout(function(){
    slideActive=true;
    $('.SliderTooltips li#st_'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","none");
});
```

the webpage code:

```
<div id="imgScroller">
    <div class="SliderButton" id="left_button"><img src="img/gallery/galerieArrowLeft.gif" alt="<"/></div>
    <div class="SliderImages">
        <ul>
        <?php
            $ze=0;
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                $ze++;
                $url_img = getFP_image_url("fpGallery_Big");
                echo "<li id='$ze'><img src='".$url_img."'/></li>";
            endwhile;
        ?>
        </ul>   

    </div>
    <div class="SliderButton" id="right_button"><img src="img/gallery/galerieArrowRight.gif" alt=">"/></div>
    <ul class="SliderTooltips">
        <?php
            $ze=0;
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                $ze++;
                $title = get_the_title();
            echo "<li id='st_$ze'><span>".$title."</span><h6> >> Zum Artikel</h6></li>";
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

What could be the reason that it close the Tooltip div until i go over it...
Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's own hover function, it ignores over/out events from children...

```
$('.SliderImages ul li').hover(function(){ 
  slideActive=false; 
  $('.SliderTooltips li#st_'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","block"); 
}, (function(){ 
  slideActive=true; 
  $('.SliderTooltips li#st_'+$(this).attr("id")).css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: can you put it online somewhere? jsfiddle.net?